# Trying to add mark.js into the svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am beginner with javascript's world and svelte. And I am trying to import an external library into the svelte app that can highlight words.

However, I am running out the ideas. For example, I am trying to utilize:

```
import { Mark } from './mark.js';
```

But it shows the following error:

```
'Mark' is not exported by src\routes\mark.js, imported by src\routes\page.svelte
```

Comment: are you making named export as Mark in mark.js file

Comment: I am using this library: https://markjs.io/

Comment: try this import {Mark} from 'mark' or if its a default export try this one import Mark from 'mark'. Check this and let me know if it worked for you

Comment: It works. If you like, you can put it as the answer.

Answer (score -2):

In my react app `import Mark from 'mark.js';` works fine after installing with `yarn`